# Call Delegate method from UIPopover

Tags: iphone, delegates, uipopover

I have a popover that gets loaded with a navigation controller, which displays the ItemsView xib, and I have a delegate method so this popover can be dismissed from the main view controller.  This works perfectly fine, until I drill down to the next level in the UITableView (which loads a detail view).  Once the detail view is loaded, I can not call the dismiss method on the main view controller.  I am quite new to delegates and would appreciate any guidance. Thank you!

MainView ---> ItemsView -----> DetailView

How to call delegate method located on MainView from DetailView?

```
//Load the popover with first view:

    ItemsView *popoverView = [[ItemsView alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popoverView];

self.popOverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController] autorelease];

popoverView.delegate = self;

[navController release];

[popOverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(450.0, 300.0)];
[popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:addButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];

[popoverView release];
```

Now I push the detail view:

```
//Push DetailView

    if(self.secondView == nil) {

    NSLog(@"Called");

    AddDetail *viewController = [[AddDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddDetail" bundle:nil];

    self.secondView = viewController;

    [viewController release];

}

// Setup the animation

secondView.contentSizeForViewInPopover = self.view.bounds.size;
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = self.view.bounds.size;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.secondView animated:YES];


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Write a property and method in Detail view like following.

- Property as id myParent
- Method as  (void)setParent:parent { myParent = parent;}

> while pushing detailviewcontroller call this method as.

- [detailViewcontroller setParent:self];

> now you can call the method declared in Parent as

- [myParent yourMethodName];

Hope this helps

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for solving this mystery for me!